# How can I save After Editing the Fulfilment in inline editor in dialog flow

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can I save After Editing the Fulfilment in inline editor in dialog flow. Because after editing the fulfilment code when I go to intent or the other tabs the changes done in fulfilment are disappearing and I couldn't find save option near fulfilment. Please help???

Answer (score 0):

At first , I couldn't save my fulfilment code as I couldn't see save option. Later, I found for saving the fulfilment code first click on Deploy button and after deploying your code   Disable your Inline Editor and you can see Save option and click on save.